# What does this statement mean in C++ concept and why it cannot works

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying C++20 features, and I want to use `concept` to restrain the template to pass only the class with a member named `List` and its type should be `std::vector<int>` . Here is the foreword.

To do this without using `concept`, I will write this code:

```
class RandomClass
{
public:
    std::vector<int> List;
};

typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(T::List), std::vector<int>>::value>::type
func(T& arg)
{
      ...
}

int main()
{
    auto randomObj= RandomClass();
    func(randomObj);
}
```

I asked New Bing to use `concept` to rewrite it, and it gave this:

```
template<class T>
concept HasList = requires(T t) {
    { t.List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>;
};

template<class T> requires HasList<T>
void func(T& arg)
```

But this code cannot be compiled, and the compiler gave `'func': no matching overloaded function found` .

I then search `std::same_as` usage and tried this:

```
template<class T>
concept HasList = requires(T t) {
    std::same_as<AddressListType, decltype(T::List)>;
};
```

This code worked.

Now here is the questions:

1. What does the symbol in these statement `{ t.List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>;` mean? I have no idea where this `{}` and `->` come from
2. Why `{ t.List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>;` cannot work?

Comment: You asked Bing this? I wouldn't trust it to come up with a reasonable answer (yet). My advise first learn a bit more about concepts yourself before rewriting code.  Anyway `{t.List} -> std::same_as<T>` means member List of t must be of type T, and its the syntax concepts uses. At least read this [cppreference constraints and concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). So summary, you still need to read documentation (and not depend on AI's alone)

Comment: "why it cannot works" ?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks for your advice, I tend to learn new things by reading existing code (in this case I use AI to generate simple example) and trying to understand it. I do read cppreference, but I haven't read this yet.

Comment: Note that `requires(T t) { std::same_as<AddressListType, decltype(T::List)>; };` merely checks that `std::same_as<AddressListType, decltype(T::List)>;` compiles, not that it is true! You need `requires(T t) { requires std::same_as<AddressListType, decltype(T::List)>; };` as g++ suggests in its warnings.

Comment: @Kulo C++ is a bit too complex for that you really need to build it up step by step. My problem with existing code is that C++ keeps evolving and most examples are outdated (probably not for concepts ;) ).
The latest insights can be found here : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: Simply use C++98. This syntax is not "normal". C++ complexity becomes an end in itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's just one small issue with your concept: The member variable is considered a *reference* to a vector. Using the following version of the concept should work:

```
template<class T>
concept HasList = requires(T t) {
    { t.List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>&>;
};
```

Note that this concept is also fulfilled for cases where the member variable type is a reference to non-const, or where `List` is a static member. You may need to revise the check, if you're bothered about those cases.

```
template<class T>
concept HasList = requires
{
    { &T::List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int> T::*>; // check, if the T::List is a pointer to a non-static member variable of type std::vector<int> 
};
```

---

In:

```
{ t.List } -> std::same_as<std::vector<int>>;
```

`t.List` is an expression, and `std::same_as<std::vector<int>>` is a concept that must be satisfied. Specifically:

```
std::same_as<X, std::vector<int>>
```

must be satisfied for `X` being the type of the expression `t.List`.

Comment: A member declared as `std::vector<int>& List` will also pass the check.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit You're right. The concept would also apply for types that have a static member variable, but these cases are irrelevant in 99% of the cases. I added an alternative that fixes this (checking, if `&T::List` is a pointer to t member variable of the required type...